# favicon disappears

Tags: php, hyperlink, favicon

Why the **favicon disappears**

Background:

I have my site made according to mvc
So, I will have a frontcontroller and a main layout
All the other views will be loaded in the $content variable from the main layout. 
The main layout holds the  tags withe the link rel "shortcut favicon".

The favicon disappears when I klik on a link in a child view.
This happens with **firefox**.

*IE is ok, but is more persistant anyway, even if you want to get rid of it.*

So, in short, - is there an explanation for this, maybe?

Comment: What's the exact code you use for the favicon element? And do you see it in the rendered HTML for those pages that the icon is missing?

Comment: Thanks---<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" > I take a look in the source code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" >
```

to make sure you are always pointing to the web root.

Comment: Thanks for seeing this, that was sinple enough

Answer (score 1):

Do all the resulting HTML pages in your child view contain the proper `<link>` tag for your favicon?

Does the link tag's `href` reference an absolute path?

Could it be that you visited your child view's output before your favicon existed, and your missing favicon is actually being cached?